# Where is CreateNewWindow located?

Tags: c++, macos, macos-carbon

I am doing a first-time project on OS X and I am trying to make a Carbon window. After adding `#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>` I was able to resolve all errors about `WindowRef` but I still get compilation errors on `CreateNewWindow`. Reading through Google shows that this function is deprecated since 10.6 (am I getting this right?). If so, what is the proper way to create a Carbon window without involving Cocoa and Objective-C?

Answer (score 2):

`CreateNewWindow()` is part of the Carbon Window Manager API. It was deprecated -- along with the vast majority of Carbon -- with the release of macOS 10.8 in 2012.

Do not use the Carbon API for new development. It has been deprecated since 2012, and cannot be used in 64-bit applications. This means that it is unsupported in macOS 10.15 (Catalina), as support for 32-bit executables has been removed in that release.

(This may be what is causing your compilation errors, incidentally. Xcode targets x86_64 by default for all new macOS projects, and Carbon is not available in 64-bit applications.)

If you don't want to use Cocoa, consider using one of the available cross-platform user interface APIs, like wxWindows or QT. Don't use Carbon -- it's dead.